# Get attribute value from different elements (simpleXML)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I would like to know if there is a way to get XML attribute values from different elements by using SimpleXML?

Considering the following XML:

```
<element1>
    <sub-element1 color="red">Content</sub-element1>
</element1>
<element2>
    <sub-element2 color="blue">Content</sub-element>
</element2>
```

I would like to parse this xml to get :

```
red
blue
```

Please note that the "color" attribute may exist in more than 30 different elements so I don't want to select the attribute element by element.

Thank you for your help!

Damien

Comment: That's not proper XML, Proper XML would have element1 and element2 as children in a parent element. There can only be one root of an XML document.

Comment: of course there is a root element "main-element".

Comment: Do you have some code to show us what you've been attempting? And abusing @skrilled is not helpful. The fragment that you've shown us is just that, a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath expression to get `color` attribute of any element in the XML document :

```
//*/@color
```

Notice that you can use `*` to reference *element of any name*, and use `@*` to reference *attribute of any name* in XPath.

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/426590)</kbd>** :

```
$string = <<<XML
<root>
    <element1>
        <sub-element1 color="red">Content</sub-element1>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <sub-element2 color="blue">Content</sub-element2>
    </element2>
</root>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$colors = $xml->xpath("//*/@color");
foreach($colors as $color){
    echo $color ."\r\n";
}
```

**output :**

```
red
blue
```